# Attaching a CSV string to an email

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to attach CSV data to an email but "Send-MailMessage" does not accept it as an -attachment parameter.  I want to avoid creating a file. Is there a way to send the content straight to the email as an attachment.

```
$attachment =  $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

Send-MailMessage 
-From $from 
-To $to 
-Subject $subject 
-Body $emailbody 
...
-Attachments $attachment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not using `Send-MailMessage` anyways.

The `-Attachments` parameter accepts *paths to files*, not arbitrary string data:

```
# create a temp file
$tmpFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

# export data to file
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $tmpFile.FullName

# rename to something sensible
$tmpFile = (Rename-Item $tmpFile -NewName "report.csv" -PassThru).FullName

# send mail
Send-MailMessage ... -Attachments $tmpFile

# clean up
Remove-Item $tmpFile
```

---

If you don't mind re-implementing much of `Send-MailMessage` by hand, you might be able to create the attachment from memory without writing it to disk:

```bsh
$msg = [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage]::new()
# ...
$attachmentData =  $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
$attachment = [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString(($attachmentData -join [environment]::NewLine), "report.csv")
$msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
# ...
```

Comment: But if I use Export-CSV that creates a temp file automatically doesn't it?  I was hoping to do it without creating a file at all.

Comment: @John As I mentioned at the top, `-Attachments` only accepts paths to files, so there's not really any way around it :)

Comment: Are you attempting to avoid cleanup of a temp file or something like that? You're not going to be able to create file and attach it to an email without writing the file somewhere. "Somewhere" can be memory if you want to go through all of the overhead, but way more trouble than it is worth unless there is no other option.

Comment: @John Added a file-less option to the answer (I haven't used the Mail API in ages, so not sure if this will work without specifying the content type)

Comment: That worked!   However the resulting excel file has the column names and data on the same line.  Is that something that should be formatted at the query level?  I assume a CSV in string form is missing excel style formatting that it has when you export it to a file?

Comment: Oh wait I didn't see your NewLine half of that line!  It works!